# tell me the meaning of these solr classes

Tags: solr

I am learning **solr** . please tell me the meaning and use of these classes ?

```
solr.StandardFilterFactory
solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory
solr.StopFilterFactory
solr.SynonymFilterFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the description available at below link.

If you don't get anything out it , you can come back with specific question where we could discuss more about it.

Here its been described with examples ...how they work and can be used.

[solr filters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions)